# Toggle div on div click horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a div which has a background image of a face, I have designed div which contains a paragraph, 2 buttons and an input box.

I know this question has been asked quite often however my situation is different, I'd like for my div with the background image of a face to be clickable so that the div containing everything else slides out from the left.

What is the best method to do this?

**HTML**

```
<div id="image"></div>
<div id="container">

<p>I like nutella and croissants</p>

<input id="message" placeholder="type...." required="required" autofocus>

 <button type="button" id="send">Send</button>
 <button type="button" id="close">Close</button>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div#image { background: url(http://i.imgur.com/PF2qPYL.png) no-repeat; }
```

**JQUERY**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$( "#image" ).click(function() {
    jQuery(this).find("#container").toggle();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [article link](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions/) posted by Raimov (which I actually came across in a Google search before realize he posted it as well ;), we can use jQuery to animate the width when the toggling element is clicked. Remember that a background does not add size to an element, so the toggle with the background image must have a height attribute set. Also, if you have long lines of text in the form, you'll have to wrap them yourself or use another method from the article.

http://jsfiddle.net/iansan5653/wp23wrem/ is a demo, and here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#image").click(function () {
        $("#container").animate({width: 'toggle'});
    });
});
```

and this CSS is necessary:

```
div#image {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/PF2qPYL.png) no-repeat;
    height: 36px;
    /*height needed to actually show the div (default width is 100%)*/
}

#container {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: That's great, thank you! Is there any way I can make the container invisible until I click on the image? And why is it overflow: hidden?

Answer (score 0):

I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aj634g0z/41/) for you, where after clicking on img, the form hides to the left.

```
$("#image").click(function() { 
var $lefty = $(this).children(); //get the #container you want to hide
$lefty.animate({
  left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ?
    -$lefty.outerWidth() : 0
});
```

The resource was taken from:
[Tutorial how to slide elements in different directions](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions/).